# SQL Server 2008 Express Prerequisite fails

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2008-express

I have an application which has SQL Server 2008 Express as a prerequisite.

The installation fails in Windows 8 Pro however with the following error message:

> Installing using command
>   'C:\Users\Ranjith\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD26C2.tmp\SqlExpress2008\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE'
>   and parameters '/q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL
>   /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 /sqlsvcaccount="NT
>   Authority\Network Service" /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin
>   /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck'  Process exited with code -2068643839 
>   Status of package 'SQL Server 2008 Express' after install is
>   'InstallFailed'

What does the exit code `-2068643839` mean?

NOTE: Tried posting in social.msdn.microsoft.com with not much responses.

Comment: SQL Server 2008  installed on Windows 8 requires a minimum of Service Pack 3, you can download the SQL Server 2008 SP3 from the following link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27597

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/822f9449-ccdd-48a4-a7d3-f02fd5a20496